# Simplifying fraction containing Abs

Tags: simplifying-expressions

The original formula looks like this:

```
Abs[(b x0^2)/(2 a) - (a y0^2)/(2 b)]/Sqrt[x0^2 + y0^2]
```

How to get:

```
Abs[(b^2 x0^2 - a^2 y0^2)/(a b)]/(2 Sqrt[x0^2 + y0^2])
```

Comment: `Abs[(b x0^2)/(2 a) - (a y0^2)/(2 b) // Together]/Sqrt[x0^2 + y0^2]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
Together /@ Abs[(b x0^2)/(2 a) - (a y0^2)/(2 b)]/Sqrt[x0^2 + y0^2]
```